# Typescript Object is possibly undefined after type guard error TS2532

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, feathersjs

I'm using Typescript `2.3.4`, Node.JS `8.0.0`, and the Feathers framework (version `2.1.1`). I am making an express route that uses a service, and when I try to use the service after grabbing the singleton instance on the feathers app, Typescript is throwing an *error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'* error, even after an explicit type guard.

**routes.ts**

```
import feathers = require('feathers');

export default function(this: feathers.Application) {
  const app = this;

  app.post(
    '/donuts',
    async (req, res) => {
      const someService = app.service<any>('predefined-service');

      if(typeof someService === "undefined" || !authService) {
        res.redirect('/fail');
        return;
      }

      try {
        let data = someService.create({test: 'hello'});
        console.log(data);
        res.redirect('/success');
      } catch(err) {
        res.redirect('/fail');
      }
    }
}
```

I've also tried writing `someService!.create...` but that didn't work either.

Comment: What is the type of someService? What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Error is on  `let data = someService.create({test: 'hello'});` line, and `someService` is defined as a `Service<any>` type as per the `app.service<any>('predefined-service')` call (that type comes from feathers).

Feathers services work [by first registering them](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers#see-it-in-action).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [Feathers typings](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/blob/master/index.d.ts):

```
interface Service<T> extends events.EventEmitter {

  create?(data: T | T[], params?: Params, callback?: any): Promise<T | T[]>;
```

The `create` method itself is optional (for whatever reason). If you're sure the method exists you could put the `!` operator after, like this:

```
let data = someService.create!({test: 'hello'});
```

Comment: That makes sense, some services won't expose `create` or other REST end points, as user defined services can basically do anything they want.

Comment: Can someone explain the job of the '!' in this context? Is it just saying "I know it will be 'defined', so don't worry about showing me any warnings... I'm not worried"

Comment: Yep, exactly. It was added in TS 2.0. They call it the "type assertion operator" or "non-null assertion operator" (though it works with undefined as well). It has no runtime effect.